# Is there any way to determine the node which has maximum amount of leaf-to-leaft node go through it on tree?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

Here I have a dp-on-tree problem needs helped. So, the tree has N node and N - 1 edges, and a leaf-to-leaf path is a path from a leaf-node to another leaf-node on tree. Therefore, if the tree has M leaf, the total path will be M * (M + 1) / 2.

How can I find the node which has maximum leaf-to-leaf path go through it? For example, if I have the tree like this, the answer will be node 2. All the paths go through node 2 are: {1 -> 6, 1 -> 7, 6 -> 7, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 6, 4 -> 7, 1 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 5 -> 7}.

I think it's a dp-on-tree problem, but I can't find out the function and dp-formula.

Thks you so much! Also, pls show me some line of code if available.

[Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omjmI.png)

Comment: I don't see how this is Dynamic Programming. Seems very straightforward. Count the number of leaves under each node. Then the number of paths going through a node is `sum_(i != j) ( leaves(i) * leaves(j) )` - that is, for each pair of sub-trees, number of leaves under one times number of leaves under the other. Pick a node where the result is the largest. I think the whole thing can be done in one depth-first traversal.

Comment: Oh, it's really simple like that? Maybe I was thinking too much. Thks u so much!

Comment: Did u mean the number of path going through node u is equal to sum(i != j)( leaves(i) * leaves(j) ) with i and j are two different children of node u?

Comment: Yes. Sum over all pairs of children. Every path going through a node would come up from some child, then go down to another child.

Comment: How abt the paths between leaves in tree root u and leaves which are not belong to tree root u? I think it should be counted too.

Comment: If those should be counted, too, then in your example it's node 3 that should win. There are 5 leaf-to-leaf paths going through it (5-4, 5-7, 5-6, 4-7, 4-6) while only 4 going through node 2 (5-7, 5-6, 4-7, 4-6). I also don't understand why you count paths like 1-6, when 1 is not a leaf.

Comment: Opps, my mistake. I forgot to tell u guys, the original problem say that a node is called a leaf if it has ONLY ONE  adjacent node. So, in the example we have 1, 4, 5, 6 and 7 are leaf nodes. @IgorTandetnik

Comment: Then it ain't a tree, but a general graph. Hopefully acyclic, otherwise "the number of paths" becomes meaningless.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I don't think so? An undirected connected graph has N verticals and N - 1 edges is a tree, I read it in book. So in this case, the graph must be a tree

Answer (score 0):

Given a suitable `struct node { int id; node *left, *right;}` and pre-created tree:

```
std::tuple<node*, int> max_candidate{nullptr, -1};
void report(node *root, int paths) {
    if (paths > std::get<1>(max_candidate)) {
        max_candidate = {root, paths};
    }
}

int visit(node *root) {
    if (!root)
        return 0;
    if (!root->left && !root->right)
        return 1;

    int leaves_left = visit(root->left);
    int leaves_right = visit(root->right);
    report(root, leaves_left * leaves_right);
    return leaves_left + leaves_right;
}
```

Comment: Note that the tree in the example shown is not binary; there's a node with three children.

Comment: I don't think so. Each node can contains many children, so this struct seems not suitable...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes u are right, that what's i'm thinking =)))

Comment: @LamCherry The principle is the same though. Extending it to general trees is perhaps best left as an exercise for the reader.